# Royal Road to Moduli Spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

I would like to ask if someone could give me an outline of fundamental works and articles to understand the most important moduli spaces, such as the moduli space of curves, vector bundles, etc... It would be nice to see different approaches to these constructions such rigidification of problems and the use of the G.I.T. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Here is a similar mathoverflow question with some very good answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44125/what-is-a-good-introductory-text-for-moduli-theory